# strncat adds some unexpected characters

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm trying to read files from a directory and to write some informations in "corresponding" files in an other directory. And to get the path and names to new files I concatenate some string using strncat function.
My problem is, strncat add somes characters at the begining of some strings, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code :

```
#define TRACES "../traces3/"
#define CSV "../csv/"

FILE* trace;
FILE* unite;
FILE* dizaine;

// Ouvre les fichiers de trace et de résultats
void ouverture (char* nom) {
    char* nTra;
    char* nUni;
    char* nDiz;
printf ("%s\n", CSV);

    nTra=malloc ((strlen (TRACES)+strlen (nom)+30)*sizeof (char));
    if (nTra==NULL) {
        printf ("Une erreure est survnue lors d'une allocation mémoire\n");
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (0);
    }
    strncat (nTra, TRACES, strlen (TRACES));
printf ("nTra : %s\n", nTra);
    strncat (nTra, nom, strlen (nom));

printf ("nTra : %s\n", nTra);

    nUni=malloc ((strlen (CSV)+strlen (nom)+30)*sizeof (char));
    if (nUni==NULL) {
        printf ("Une erreure est survnue lors d'une allocation mémoire\n");
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (0);
    }
    strncat (nUni, CSV, strlen (CSV));
printf ("nUni : %s\n", nUni);
    strncat (nUni, nom, strlen (nom)-3);
printf ("nUni : %s\n", nUni);
    strncat (nUni, "U.csv", 5);

printf ("nUni : %s\n", nUni);

    nDiz=malloc ((strlen (CSV)+strlen (nom)+30)*sizeof (char));
    if (nDiz==NULL) {
        printf ("Une erreure est survnue lors d'une allocation mémoire\n");
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (0);
    }
    strncat (nDiz, CSV, strlen (CSV));
printf ("nDiz : %s\n", nDiz);
    strncat (nDiz, nom, strlen (nom)-3);
printf ("nDiz : %s\n", nDiz);
    strncat (nDiz, "D.csv", 5);

printf ("nDiz : %s\n", nDiz);

    trace=fopen (nTra, "r");
    unite=fopen (nUni, "w");
    dizaine=fopen (nDiz, "w");

    free (nTra);
    free (nUni);
    free (nDiz);
}
```

And here is the result in a terminal :

```
nom :    red-queueS1D16.tr
../csv/
nTra : ../traces3/
nTra : ../traces3/red-queueS1D16.tr
nUni : ../csv/
nUni : ../csv/red-queueS1D16
nUni : ../csv/red-queueS1D16U.csv
nDiz : ../csv/
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS1D16
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS1D16D.csv
nom :    red-queueS2D16.tr
../csv/
nTra : ../traces3/
nTra : ../traces3/red-queueS2D16.tr
nUni : ��$../csv/
nUni : ��$../csv/red-queueS2D16
nUni : ��$../csv/red-queueS2D16U.csv
nDiz : ../csv/
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS2D16
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS2D16D.csv
nom :   red-queueS17D19.tr
../csv/
nTra : ../traces3/
nTra : ../traces3/red-queueS17D19.tr
nUni : а$../csv/
nUni : а$../csv/red-queueS17D19
nUni : а$../csv/red-queueS17D19U.csv
nDiz : ../csv/
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS17D19
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS17D19D.csv
nom :   red-queueS17D18.tr
../csv/
nTra : ../traces3/
nTra : ../traces3/red-queueS17D18.tr
nUni : ��$../csv/
nUni : ��$../csv/red-queueS17D18
nUni : ��$../csv/red-queueS17D18U.csv
nDiz : ../csv/
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS17D18
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS17D18D.csv
nom :    red-queueS3D21.tr
../csv/
nTra : ../traces3/
nTra : ../traces3/red-queueS3D21.tr
nUni : а$../csv/
nUni : а$../csv/red-queueS3D21
nUni : а$../csv/red-queueS3D21U.csv
nDiz : ../csv/
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS3D21
nDiz : ../csv/red-queueS3D21D.csv
```

So, is anyone who can help me ?

Thanks for all help ;)
Phantom

Comment: Can you reduce your example to a (much) smaller program that still produces the error?

Comment: Hint: You could use `snprintf()` instead. BTW: `strncat()` does not *add* the characters, they are already there.

Comment: You appear to never *initialize* your newly allocated strings. You allocate memory for them, but you never assign anything string like (or even the `'\0'` value) to them, thus they contain random garbage, to which you concatenate something. You could try and use `calloc` instead, or follow up on joop's hint.

Comment: @joop : I thought about snprintf(), but I remove some characters from the string I add, so it will be harder (for me).

Comment: @Evert : I initialize the new string with '\0', add the problem is gone. Thanks for your anser

Comment: BTW: `strncat (nTra, TRACES, strlen (TRACES));` is completely wrong, the target string could be longer than TRACES (if nTRA would be longer than zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

`strncat (nTra, TRACES, strlen (TRACES));`

and

`strncat (nUni, CSV, strlen (CSV));`

Are concatenating CSV into uninitialised strings that you are hoping are empty (i.e. you hope that they have been initialised with a 0 in the first byte).

You could fix this by instead doing:

`strcpy(nTra, TRACES)`

and

`strcpy(nUni, CSV)`

Comment: As I told to Evert I initialized new strings with '\0', but you way should work, I it must be better. So I'll do like this in the future. Thanks ;)

Comment: Don't use strcpy, use strncpy instead. No need to go back to unsafe functions. Also copy at most as many bytes as the destination can hold not as many as the source has.

Comment: strcpy(dest,src) is not unsafe if the OP has already allocated enough space to fit src (which they have). strncpy is not automatically safe either - the OP did strncpy(dest, src, strlen(src)). How is that an improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Example using `snprintf()` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRACES "../traces3/"
#define CSV "../csv/"
#define UCSV "U.csv"
#define DCSV "D.csv"

FILE* trace;
FILE* unite;
FILE* dizaine;

// Ouvre les fichiers de trace et de résultats
void ouverture (char* nom) {
    char* nTra;
    char* nUni;
    char* nDiz;
    size_t nlen, tlen, clen, ulen,dlen, nlen3;
    int rc;

    nlen = strlen( nom);
    tlen = strlen( TRACES);
    clen = strlen( CSV);
    ulen = strlen( UCSV);
    dlen = strlen( DCSV);

printf ("%s\n", CSV);
    nlen3  = nlen > 3 ? nlen-3 :0;

    nTra=malloc (tlen+nlen+1);
    if (!nTra) {
        printf ("Une erreure est survenu lors d'une allocation mémoire\n");
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (0);
    }
    rc = snprintf( nTra, tlen+nlen+1, "%s%s", TRACES, nom );
        /* FIXME: Check return value `rc` here */
printf ("nTra : %s\n", nTra);

    nUni=malloc (clen+nlen+ulen+1);
    if (!nUni) {
        printf ("Une erreure est survenu lors d'une allocation mémoire\n");
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (0);
    }
    rc = snprintf(nUni, clen+nlen+ulen+1, "%s%s%s", CSV, nom, UCSV);
printf ("nUni : %s\n", nUni);

    nDiz=malloc (clen)+nlen+dlen+1;
    if (nDiz==NULL) {
        printf ("Une erreure est survenu lors d'une allocation mémoire\n");
        perror ("malloc");
        exit (0);
    }
    rc = snprintf(nDiz, clen+nlen+dlen+1, "%s%.*s%s", CSV, (int) nlen3, nom, DCSV);

printf ("nDiz : %s\n", nDiz);

#if 0
    trace=fopen (nTra, "r");
    unite=fopen (nUni, "w");
    dizaine=fopen (nDiz, "w");

    free (nTra);
    free (nUni);
    free (nDiz);
#endif
}

int main (void)
{
ouverture ("OMG!/");
return 0;
}
```

UPDATED (added lenght truncation of `nom` )

Comment: Yes, but like this you don't remove the extension of the source file name. So with my example, you will have files names like .trU.csv

Comment: My program intends to mimick the exact (intended) behaviour of the pgm in your question. If you want to add/remove things you'd have to do that in either case.

Comment: In my program I remove 3 characters with strncat (nUni, nom, strlen (nom)-3);

Comment: Oops, had not seen that, sorry! BTW: To make the program fullproof, you **should** check for `strlen(nom) >= 3`, first.